# Swift how to delete childs value which is an Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

i try to delete a childs value in my document to delete. The value is an Dictionary and i need to delete the whole Dictionary but XCode says :

> Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Here is my Code:

```
var lists = [Dictionary<String, String>
             let washingtonRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid!)
             washingtonRef.updateData([
             "shoppingLists":
             FieldValue.arrayRemove(self.lists[sender.tag] as!
                 Dictionary<String,
                 String>)])
```

Comment: What's with the `[` at the start? and the redundant `)` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this code:

```
 let washingtonRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid!)

        // Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
        washingtonRef.updateData([
            "shoppingLists": FieldValue.arrayRemove([self.filteredData[sender.tag] as! Any])

            ])
```